# Chrome remove a certificate from personal store

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, https

I'm creating an API using node js and express. As we are moving towards production, I decided to encrypt the api using ssl, (simply adding the require 'https' option and creating the requires key and cert files using openssl).

I want to continue working on the API using postman (chrome plugin), so to enable me to do this, I  visited the API using Chrome, saved the cert for the API to disk and then imported that cert file (cer format) to the "personal" certificate store in Chrome. So far, so simple.

I was then able to start using the API over ssl as expected. Great.

Now, where it is starting to get a bit odd is that if I want to then remove that certificate from my personal certificate store in chrome, I was expecting to be able to just open up the settings - > htttps  - > manage certificates and then to be able to remove the certificate, however the certificate is not visible in the list of certs. It's clearly been imported and is working, it's just not showing in the list. The machine in question is running win 10, so I also checked the certificate management console for the machine and I searched for the cert and cannot find it anywhere.

I think that this should be really simple, so where is that cert that I imported (and which is clearly imported and working) so that I can remove it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

So, I finally found the solution to this. From the command line start "certmgr" and from there I can see the installed certificate and remove it. Not sure why it doesn't show up when viewed from within Chrome?!